What is the equation of the evolute of a curve given in implicit equation?
I am trying to find the evolute of a curve given in implicit equation. I tried to find it using the definition, as the envelope of the family of normals, however I didn't come to a conclusion.
Then I tried to consider it as the geometric locus of points of the centers of curvature:
The curvature:
$$ \kappa = \frac{F_x^2 F_{yy} - 2 F_x F_y F_{xy} + F_y^2 F_{xx}}{(F_x^2 + F_y^2)^{3/2}}
   $$
The radius of curvature:
$$
   R = \frac{1}{|\kappa|}
   $$
The center of curvature (the coordinates of the center of the osculating circle):
$$
   X = x - R \frac{F_y}{\sqrt{F_x^2 + F_y^2}}
   $$
$$
   Y = y + R \frac{F_x}{\sqrt{F_x^2 + F_y^2}}
   $$
Is this okay?
(Ps. I am new to differential geometry so please be kind :)

The direction of the center of curvature seen from a point on the curve is parallel to the gradient of $F,$ so in your last equations the signs in front of $R$ must either be both postive, or both negative. Which of the two it is probably depends on the sign of $\kappa.$
